# Упорядочить строки массива по значению элемента главной диагонали в каждой из строк (в начальном массиве)

Tags: c++

Упорядочить строки массива по значению элемента главной диагонали в каждой из строк (в начальном массиве).

```
[[3, 2, 7, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8],
[5, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 6, 7],
[1, 9, 7, 8, 2, 1, 3, 7, 9, 8],
[1, 7, 3, 7, 6, 6, 6, 8, 4, 8],
[4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6]]
```

Есть такой массив, как он должен выглядеть в результате?

Comment: Вы  по диагонали должны достичь либо дна, либо правого борта,  превдварительно отсортировав  строки, но это если я правильно понимаю  задачу

Comment: Можете пример, привести на массиве, который я задал

Comment: Проведите диагональ на ней лежат числа 3 3 7 7 2. Вот согласно их значениям нужно упорядочить соотв. строки

Comment: @MBo Например, для первой строки 3 и как она должна выглядеть в результате?

Comment: Строка не изменится, но строки нужно поменять местами, последняя встанет на первое место

Comment: @MBo Но при этом получится диагональ 4 2 7 8 6 - опять неупорядоченная? Может, надо строки упорядочить как 1 9 7, потом 4 2 3, 1 7 3 ну и так далее?

Comment: @Mikhailo Тут задание, конечно, сомнительное. Я исходил из  того, что `(в начальном массиве)` упоминается, и более логичной интерпретации не нашёл

Comment: @Mikhailo [5, 1, 4, 8, 5]
[6, 8, 3, 3, 2]
[5, 7, 3, 1, 2]
[1, 8, 4, 6, 3]
[3, 3, 1, 8, 9]  есть такая матрица, как она должна выглядеть в конце, по вашей версии

Comment: [1, 8, 4, 6, 3][3, 3, 1, 8, 9][5, 7, 3, 1, 2][6, 8, 3, 3, 2][5, 1, 4, 8, 5]